# How many nodes should a cluster should have in order to analyse 3 TB of data? how should one design the hardware architecture

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, bigdata

Description: The data is in SQL Server database and we need to analyse this data with the help of big data

any help in this regard would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, hence I will give a very generic solution:

## One off analyisis

If you only need to do an analysis once, here is what I would recommend:

Set up a cluster in the cloud, this allows you to get huge capacity for a very short time (and thus a very small cost).

You can basically set up a small master node, and 3 slave nodes with about 5TB each.

If it turns out halfway that you are lacking a bit of disk space, don't bother going for bigger nodes but just add one or a few data nodes to the cluster.

## Structural/daily analysis

If setting up a cluster in the cloud is not feasible or desirable, you can set it up on your own hardware.

For this it is very critical to think about how the size is going to develop (and whether you want to buy for potential growth). It is also important to realize that over time you may need more complex operations, or you may get data duplication due to the nature of your analysis.

If I were to recommend a setup for 3TB of starting data, I would go for something more heavy than what I recommended before.

For instance, assuming mild but significant growth:
2 master nodes, and 5 slave nodes with 10 TB each.

Comment: Thank You for the answer